# Modify CSS element on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on the following page: http://mockingbirdagency.com/thebox/bettercss/login-1.html
I know very little Javascript so please dumb it down for me.

I would like "Register with your email address" to be centered on the block and to go at the top of it (by deleting margin-top: 30px;) when clicked on (the idea being not to have such a big block).

How can I add this to the JS function ??

Thanks!

Comment: could you add some mark up please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your jquery click handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').click(function() {
        $('#details').toggle(500);
    });
});
```

you need to add

```
$(this).css("margin-top","");
```

the final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').click(function() {
        $(this).css("margin-top","");
        $('#details').toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use jquery for this so as a basic guide:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

So when you click the item with an ID of target this would show an alert box saying: "Handler for .click() called."

So now you want to add a style to that item you clicked

```
$("#target").click(function() {
      $(this).css("margin-top","0");
    });
```

So, now you hit the item, it runs and adds the CSS of margin-top:0; to 'this' which is the item triggering the event.

Obviously you will need to change #target to the ID of the item you want the event to trigger on, you can also use .target and apply to an item with only a class.

Find out more at http://jquery.com

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
$("#hh").click(function(){
    $(this).css("margin-top","0px");
});
```